# Uncaught error when using Semantic UI in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use semantic UI in react but I have a problem:

In App.jsx:

```
import BlogDashboard from '../../features/blog/BlogDashboard/BlogDashboard';
import BlogDetailedPage from '../../features/blog/BlogDetail/BlogDetailedPage';
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
            <Route
            path='/(.+)'
            render={() => (
            <Fragment>
                <NavBar />
                <Container className="main">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/blogs' component={BlogDashboard} />
                        <Route path='/blogs/:id' component={BlogDetailedPage} />
                    </Switch>
                </Container>
            </Fragment>
            )} 
        />
        </Fragment>
    );
}
}
export default App;
```

In BlogDetailsPage:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import BlogDetailedHeader from './BlogDetailedHeader'

const BlogDetailedPage = () => {
return (

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
            <BlogDetailedHeader />
        </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
 )
}
export default BlogDetailedPage;
```

In BlogDetailedHeader:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Segment, Image, Item, Header, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
const BlogDetailedHeader = () => {

return (    
    <Segment.Group>
        <Segment basic attached="top" style={{padding: '0'}}>
            <Image src="/assets/categoryImages/HoiAn.jpg" fluid  />
            <Segment basic style={blogImageTextStyle}>
                <Item.group>
                   <Item>
                       <Item.Content>
                            <Header side="huge" content="Blog title" style={{color: 'white'}} />
                            <p>Date</p>
                            <p>Posted by <strong>posted by</strong></p>
                       </Item.Content>
                   </Item>
                </Item.group>
            </Segment>
        </Segment>

        <Segment attached="bottom">
            <Button>Cancel</Button>
            <Button color='teal' >like</Button>
            <Button color='orange' floated="right">Edit</Button>
        </Segment>

    </Segment.Group>
)
}

export default BlogDetailedHeader;
```

Now If I replace the code in the return of BlogDetailedHeader component to a div-tag like `<div>Hello</div>` or any HTML tag, It will work fine (which means the BlogDetailedPage can display the content from BlogDetailedHeader) but when I use semantic UI component in the code, React throw me an error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for 
composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file 
it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Could you replace the component calling <BlogDetailedHeader /> with {BlogDetailedHeader} ?

Comment: @Max, If I do that, there will be another error, the 'BlogDetailedHeader' is not exported from './BlogDetailedHeader'

Answer (score 0):

I found it, It's the Group attribute in Image component, the first letter should be capitalized: `<Image.Group> </Image.Group>`, thanks for helping.